How to update a single-cell value in plotly dash ag grid?
I am a bit new to Plotly Dash and AG Grid, but basically I am creating an Ag grid with dash and i am trying to update a cell value based on another editable cell:
curves_grid = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LITERA])

# Define the layout of the app
gbp_curves_grid.layout = html.Div([
    dag.AgGrid(
        id='curves_grid',
        columnDefs=[
            {'field': 'A', 'editable': False},
            {'field': 'B', 'editable': True},
            {'field': 'C', 'editable': False, "cellRenderer": "agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer"},
            {'field': 'D', 'editable': False},
        ],
        rowData=df_curves.to_dict("records"),
        enableEnterpriseModules=True,
        getRowId="params.data.id",
    ),

])

@curves_grid.callback(Output('curves_grid', 'rowTransaction'), 
                          Input('curves_grid', 'cellValueChanged'),
                         prevent_initial_call=True,)
def update_close(row_changed):

    if row_changed: row_changed[0]['data']['D'] = 40
    
    return {"update": row_changed}


So basically I am trying to update the cell in column D to 40 if something is entered in the cell in column B...
Any idea?
Thanks

I tested with some sample data and it's working fine. You need some adjustments in the update function like below:
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash import html
import dash_ag_grid as dag
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LITERA])

# Define the layout of the app
app.layout = html.Div([
    dag.AgGrid(
        id='curves_grid',
        columnDefs=[
            {'field': 'A', 'editable': False},
            {'field': 'B', 'editable': True},
            {'field': 'C', 'editable': False, "cellRenderer": "agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer"},
            {'field': 'D', 'editable': False},
        ],
        rowData=[
            {"id": 1, "A": 1, "B": 0, "C": 10, "D": 20},
            {"id": 2, "A": 2, "B": 0, "C": 15, "D": 25}
        ],
        enableEnterpriseModules=True,
        getRowId="params.data.id",
    ),
])

# Callback to update column D based on changes in column B
@app.callback(
    Output('curves_grid', 'rowTransaction'),
    Input('curves_grid', 'cellValueChanged'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_close(cell_changes):
    if cell_changes and isinstance(cell_changes, list):
        change = cell_changes[0]  # Get the first change event
        
        # Check if the change is in column 'B'
        if change['colId'] == 'B':
            # Get the row data and update column 'D'
            updated_row = change['data']
            updated_row['D'] = 40  # Set the value of column D to 40
            
            # Return the updated row as a transaction to update the grid
            return {"update": [updated_row]}
    
    return dash.no_update

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)


Hi, I see my mistakes..thanks working perfectly!

gr8! You can also "Accept" the answer (check the right icon) to make it the final solution to the problem, that way any user will know the particular question is answered and has found the final solution. Thanks!
